# How to make front-end page offline(only access localhost and relative path assets(js,css, png...))

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I wanna use front-end code in android webview

I hope it's offline(only can access localhost)

so how should i do?

is there chrome devtools way or js way?

Answer (score 0):

If you go in the Chrome devtools inside the "Network" tab, you can simulate an offline state:

[image]

Comment: I hope simulate android webview not internet case, it means only localhost can acces, but devtools disable localhost access